# My Codeigniter session expires automatically as soon as it is created

Tags: codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3, session-cookies

I have a problem with my **codeigniter** *login session*, session expires automatically as soon as it is create so it redirects back to the login page
regardless of the  fact that the login information is true. The session is automatically destroyed immedietly it is formed. Here is my config page.

```
//date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Istanbul");  

 $config['sess_driver'] = 'files'; 

 $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'cisession';  

 $config['sess_expiration'] = 86400;  

//$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';

 $config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'ci_sessions/'; 

 $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;

 $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;

 $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

 $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;

 $config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;

 $config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;

 $config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;

 $config['cookie_prefix']   = '';

 $config['cookie_domain']   = str_replace("http://","",str_replace("https://","", $config['base_url']));

$config['cookie_path']      = '/';

$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;

//$config['cookie_httponly']    = FALSE;
```

Comment: How can it be getting destroyed as soon as it's created? I'd be thinking it's not being created in the first place. I'd be checking that your sess_save_path exists and that it has the correct write permissions etc.

Comment: can you show us your controller code where it create a session?

Comment: which version of codeigniter? does the login script use ajax? are you/how are you verifying the session variables are being set and subsequently destroyed?

Answer (score 1):

**Please use these configuration for session in your config file.**

```
  $config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
  $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
  $config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
  $config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
  $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
  $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 600;
  $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Thank you so much...Really I appreciate it because it worked perfectly well

Comment: @Kash Shafiique .. please keep support to my answer.